# CORS problem (No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin') angular, node js, sockets io

Tags: nodejs, typescript, socket, socket.io

Buen dia, actualmente estoy en proceso de aprendizaje utilizando de backend node js y socket io, utilizo typescripe. Quiero conectar una aplicacion he hecha en angular 8. El problema es que cuando intento conectarme desde el cliente angular tengo este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intente instalar el paquete cors npm y configurarlo para solucionar este incoveniente pero ninguna de las configuraciones me ha funcionado. segun la documentacion tengo que utilizar  `this.io.origins('http://localhost:4200/');` pero no ha funcionado para mi.

server.ts
En este archivo he intentado configurar los cors desde socket io

```
private constructor(){
    this.app = express();
    this.port = SERVER_PORT; //LLEGA DESDE GLOBAL
    this.httpServer = new http.Server(this.app);
    this.io = socketIO(this.httpServer);
    this.escucharSockets();        
}
//si ya existe una instancia regrese .. si no la tiene entonces la crea
public static get  instance(){
    return this._instance || (this._instance = new this())
}

private escucharSockets(){
    console.log('escuchar conexiones - sockets');

    this.io.origins('http://localhost:4200/');
    //on significa escuchando
    this.io.on('connection', cliente =>{

        console.log('cliente conectado');
    });
}
```

index.js
En este archivo utilizo la configuracion del cors desde la libreria cors:

```
server.app.use(cors ({origin : true, credentials : true}));
```

anexo version de dependencias:

package.json

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Podrías probar desinstalando `socket.io` e instalando `socket.io-client` en la versión 3.1.2

```
npm install socket.io-client@3.1.2 --save
```

Del lado del servidor podrías verificar lo siguiente

```
const app = require('express')();
const http = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http, {
  cors: {
    origins: ['http://localhost:4200']
  }
});
```

reemplazando 'http://localhost:4200' por el ambiente donde corre tu aplicación Angular.

Answer (score 0):

recuerda incorporar las cabeceras:

```
app.use((req,res,next)=>{
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Authorization, X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Allow-Request-Method,');
    res.header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8')
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
    res.header('Allow', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
    next()
})
```